# Angular4 Universal - xhr2.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, angular-http, angular-universal

I have a problem with my universal project:

I have the following service:

```
public getData(): Observable<Article[]> {
    return this.getJson(this.relativeUrl).map(response => {
        const data = response.json();
        return data.map((item) => new Article().deserialize(item));
    })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And I make the following call:

```
private getArticles () {
    this.articleService
        .getData()
        .subscribe(
            (articles) => this.articles = articles,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        )
}
```

This works fine in my normal Angular project, however it fails if I include the **ServerModule** for Angular-Universal. Does somebody know where the problem is ?

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
//ERROR IF: import {ServerModule} from '@angular/platform-server';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
...
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
        appRoutes,
        {enableTracing: true}
    ),
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({
        appId: 'ng-cli-universal'
    }),
    HttpModule /* ERROR IF; , ServerModule*/

],
```

Comment: I know its a long, long time ago, but did you solved this issue ?